# Convert String to Date SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can I convert  String to Date type in SQL?

I have a column called timestamp (type varchar) with the following data:

```
timestamp
06.07.2021 00:00:00
05.07.2021 00:00:00
04.07.2021 00:00:00
```

I would like to run the following query which is unfortunately not working:

```
select timestamp from table where 
convert(datetime,timestamp,112) = convert(datetime, '20210706')
```

How should I replace "convert(datetime,timestamp,112)" so that it works?

Comment: Whats the problem, its already a date/time field.

Comment: Your code seems to be SQL Server but you tagged MySql. Which database are you using?

Comment: @Hermanto, mysql also has `convert` function https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert

Comment: MS SQL Server, sorry for the wrong tag.

Comment: @Grumpy the field is "varchar"

Comment: @sddk I mean, the `CONVERT` syntax is SQL server, not the function itself.

Comment: It is a very bad idea to store dates and timestamps as varchar and not in their appropriate type. Anyway, why not just `select * from table where timestamp like '06.07.2021%`?

Comment: @Hermanto, got it.

Comment: use convert(datetime,timestamp) = convert(datetime, '20210706')

Comment: @Gigi the real problem is using the wrong type and storing strings instead of dates. Don't do that. Use a proper `datetime2(0)` field to store date and time with second resolution. It actually takes less space than varchar, *and* has no sorting/localization/parsing issues. If you want to store dates, use `date`

Comment: To comparer dates, *don't* convert them to text. This prevents you from using any indexes. In any case, `convert(datetime, '20210706') ` is pointless as `YYYYMMDD` is an unambiguous date literal. It doesn't need parsing. The other unambiguous format is the ISO8601 format (ie `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss....`

Answer (score 1):

try use PARSE t-sql function

```
SELECT PARSE(timestamp AS date USING 'Ru-RU') from table
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server is actually pretty flexible on converting date/times without a format.  So, if you want to convert to a date/time, this works:

```
select convert(datetime, '06.07.2021 00:00:00')
```

If you are only looking at the date, though, you might want to limit to the first 10 characters.  If you are certain that all the strings have valid dates, you can use `104` to convert the value:

```
select cast(date, left(datetime, 10), 104)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing against date value, you can convert to date datatype and apply WHERE clause.

```sql
declare @TABLE TABLE(timestampvalue varchar(20))

INSERT into @table 
values

('06.07.2021 00:00:00'),
('05.07.2021 00:00:00'),
('04.07.2021 00:00:00');

SELECT convert(date,timestampvalue,104) FROM @table where convert(date,timestampvalue,104) = '20210706'
```

> 2021-07-06

**Note:** This type of applying CONVERT function in the WHERE clause, will make the query Non-Sargeable. It is better to change datatype to DATE and then do comparison.

```sql
UPDATE TABLE <TABLENAME>
SET TimeStampValue = CONVERT(DATE,TimeStampValue,104)
```

Now, you can ALTER table.

```sql
ALTER TABLE <TABLENAME> ALTER COLUMN TimeStampValue DATE
```

Now, you can apply the WHERE clause without conversion.

```sql
SELECT * FROM tablename where timestampvalue = '20210706'
```